# Why can't I use a variable in same function scope in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope, legend, chart.js

I'm trying to use the legendTemplate in options in Chart.js.

I have this:

```
var item1 = 5;
var item2 = 10;

function handle_chart_data(data) {
                window.item1 = data[0];
                window.item2 = data[1];

                var data = [
                {
                    value : window.item1,
                    color : "#FF0000",
                    label : "Item1"
                },
                {
                    value : window.item2,
                    color : "#5E5E5E",
                    label : "Item2"
                },
                ];

                options = {
                    segmentShowStroke: false,
                    animateRotate: true,
                    animateScale: false,
                    percentageInnerCutout: 50,
                    //legendTemplate: "<% for (var i=0; i<5; i++ ) { data.value } %>"
                }

                var ctx = document.getElementById("dgraph").getContext("2d");
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);
                document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();
                }
}
```

HTML is as such:

```
<div class="graph">
                            <canvas id="dgraph" width="300" height="200"></canvas>                            
                            <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
                        </div>
```

CSS is as follows:

```
.chart-legend li span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.graph {
    float:left;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

However, I get an uncaught reference error for data when I uncomment the content of the legendTemplate.  I'm thinking this is some kind of scope error.

Javascript scope confuses me no end as I'm from a C/C++/Python background and it's exasperatingly counter-intuitive.  To me, the scope for 'data' is the same as the scope for 'options' and therefore 'options' should be able to see 'data' but this is clearly not the case.  What on earth am I doing wrong?

Ultimately, all I really want to achieve is to remove the annoying bullets on my legend (my current code as written above will not achieve this) but I would like to understand what appears to be a trivial error on my part in the process preventing me from seeing the data variable inside the options variable at the same level (both inside the same function).

Does using brackets without entering a function change scope?  Do square brackets have different effects on scope as compared with squiggly brackets if so?

Comment: `data` in the commented out section is just part of a JavaScript string literal, and not a variable at all. It shouldn't throw a reference error. What is `<%`? It looks like you are showing use some server side code that generates some JavaScript instead of showing us the JavaScript it outputs (and which, presumably, generates the reference error).

Comment: I notice you're accessing `data.value`, not `data[i].value`. Since `data` is an array, shouldn't you be accessing it by index?

Comment: The template is invoked for each item in the dataset. It should just be `value`, not `data.value`.

Comment: @Quentin Chart.js uses John Resig's microtemplate code. The idea here is to enable generation of labels based on the data for each part of the chart.

Comment: @Rodent what is it that you expect that `for` loop in the template string to do? Why loop `5` times? Do you really want to append the `value` property 5 times?

Comment: There are actually 5 items in my data array, not 2 but I shortened it as part of my web sanitisation process.  The for loop should ideally look something like for (var i=0; i< data.length; i++) { ... } where ... is something to do with data[i].value or value alone.  What I really want is a square box of the colour of the doughnut section followed by the label as a vertical list, optionally with value also as it may also work on touchscreens and you can't hover on touch devices to obtain value.

Comment: I actually have a square box with label already but it has a bullet on the left of the square - hence the need to manually format the legend.  Also I'd like to be able to add the value as a postfix on a per item basis @Pointy.

Comment: The Chart.js donut chart code creates the label such that there are class names on the elements. You can probably get what you want by just adding some CSS rules to set the `<ul>` it generates to `list-style: none;`

Comment: ok, cool thanks @Pointy I'll look into that.  Do you have any idea about the scope issue though?

Comment: @Rodent it's not really documented, but I *think* that the template context for donut charts is the chart object itself. Well, not the context exactly; the template is interpreted as code inside a `with` statement, and that `with` statement refers to the chart object. Thus, in the default label template, `name` is the string "Doughnut" and `segments` is the array of chart data. The `<ul>` is generated with the class `doughnut-legend`.

Comment: That template syntax is awful by the way - it'd be nice if Chart would move into the modern world :)

Comment: @Pointy - thanks for your assistance

Answer (score -1):

In the loop try data[i].value instead. Data is an array in your code, but you try to reference as though it has a property it just doesn't because it's an array of objects. You'll also want i < data.length or you'll get more exceptions.

There is actually quite a bit more wrong than I initially saw, as the string literal is odd, though this may be a paste error?

Comment: This is all about a feature of Chart.js; it has nothing to do with scoping (well, not much anyway).

Comment: @Pointy Ah,  I see I was in error. I was not familiar with this aspect, I though it was more vanilla code at first.